# Example of a situation when $P(X<Y)$ is not equal to $P(X^{2} < Y^{2})$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose I have two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same sample space. Intuitively I understand that $P(X<Y)$ does not imply that $P(X^{2} < Y^{2})$, but I can't think of any explicit example, however simple, that demonstrates this - can anyone help please?

Comment: Any example will have $X$ or $Y$ possibly taking negative values. They are then easy to construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Non-degenerate r.v.'s, taking the same set of values:**

Let $X$ be $0$ with probability $1/3$ and $-1$ with probability $2/3$; and $Y$ (independent of $X$) be $0$ with probability $2/3$ and $-1$ with probability $1/3$.

$X,Y$ are discrete, non-degenerate, and both take values in $\{-1,0\}$. But
$$
\Pr[X<Y] = \frac{2}{9}, \qquad \Pr[X^2<Y^2] = \frac{1}{9}
$$

**Previous answer (with a non-degenerate r.v., not the same domain):**

Let $X$ be uniform on $\{-1,1\}$, and $Y$ be uniform on $\{0,1\}$. Then
$$
\Pr[X<Y] = \Pr[X=-1] = \frac{1}{2}
$$
but since $X^2=1$ with probability one and $Y^2=Y$,
$$
\Pr[X^2<Y^2] = \Pr[Y>1] = 0\,.
$$

You can cook up many such examples by letting $X$ taking negative values (but with $Y\geq 0$ a.s.).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but is it possible to have an example for a  discrete variable? @Clement C.

Comment: @Sasha1001 What do you mean? Both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete here ($X$ takes values either $-1$ or $1$, $Y$ is a Bernoulli).

Comment: Ah yes, of course. What about if I impose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables on the same sample space? Is it possible to come up with an example then?  @Clement C.

Comment: @sasha1001 please modify your question accordingly to add the constraints/what you exactly have in mind. I added my answer to show an example with non degenerate random variables, but as it stands the constant r.v. example by Les cygnes addresses your original question.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess the sample space can be incorporated trivially, right? I can take sample space as $S = \{H, T \}$ outcome of a coin flip. And define $X = -1$ if heads and $X = +1$ if tails, then $Y = 0$ if heads and $Y = 1$ if tails, as in your example. @ Clement C.

Comment: @Sasha1001 I have added an explicit example where both $X,Y$ have the same domain (and can be defined from the same sample space).

Comment: Thank you very much! @Clement C.

Comment: You're welcome! @Sasha1001

Answer (score 10):

Let $X$ be constantly $-1$ and $Y$ be constantly $0$. Then $P(X<Y) = 1 $ and $P(X^2 <Y^2) = 0$

Comment: Clear and to the point.  $+1$.